# How to make a real-time and scalable/adaptive search system combining aws cloudsearch and dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I want to make a high reactive search system using cloudsearch from aws.I already set a testing process between lambda and dynamodb triggers but the results aren't what i'm expecting. What i want is making my search system to fetch data dynamically and in real-time from  a dynamodb table that i created . That means, i shouldn't need to set the batch size each time i want to increase the number of record to retrieve data from my table. So, i'm seeking some scalability. 
Also i need my search system to be highly reactive. Because when there are a new entry, it could happen about one minute before it is indexed in cloudsearch. It is a lot of time. Each time i post a data, i have to wait one minute before to be able to search it. I am expecting something more reactive.

Any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: screw cloudsearch+dynamodb. AWS now has elasticsearch, which will work far better for your use case.

Comment: @ketan Thanks for the advise. This is what i was thinking. Cloudsearch seems to be a little bit limited in real-time features and thus do not fit with my expectations. I didn't know Amazon ES but after doc reading it seems that is exactly what i was sought.